# substring by char range

Tags: bash

10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv

how can i get string between every , and _

such as aaa bbb

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
string="10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv"

IFS=','                        # separator for splitting
array=( ${string#*,} )         # split string after the first comma
array=( ${array[@]%%_*} )      # delete trailing '_*' for each element

echo -e "${array[@]}"          # gives 'aaa bbb'
```

Comment: Neat :) More elegant than my solution, so you deserve +1.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example

```
echo "10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv" | grep -o ",[^_]*_"
```

well, above command will include the ',' and '_' in the output
To exclude this you may use

```
echo "10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv" | pcregrep -o "(?<=,).*?(?=_)"
```

The regex `(?<=,).*?(?=_)` passed to the pcregrep plays the important role using 'lookbehind' and 'lookahead' technique of regex which is supported by 'pcregrep'

Answer (score 0):

```
$ s="10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv"
$ echo $s|tr "_" "\n"|sed -n '/,/s/.*,//p'
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is a pure Bash-solution, i.e. you do not want to call external programs, you could try something like this:

```
str=10.11.183.81,aaa_XXX150.csv,bbb_YYYY_20100807.csv

while [[ "$str" =~ "," ]]; do
    str=${str#*,}
    echo ${str%%_*}
done
```

Output is:

```
aaa
bbb
```

The while loop executes as long as there is at least one remaining comma in the string. Then the first line removes all characters from the left side of the string up to and including the first comma, and the second line prints the string excluding everything from the first underscore to the end of the string.

Note that the original string ($str) is modified.